# access global variables in nested functions

Tags: javascript, function

I need to access global variables in a nested function how would I do that?

```js
let x = 0
function one() {
    console.log(x)
}
function two() {
    two()
}
```

should log 0 but gets error "x is undefined"

Comment: You haven't called either of the functions...

Comment: in function two it should be one() not two()

Comment: You still need to call `two()`.

Comment: no I mean that it get's the error when call two, is what I meant

Comment: `;` is missing.

Comment: You wouldn't get that error with the code you posted. You would get some kind of call stack related error since you have infinite recursion.

Comment: @lusitanica It's optional, though some (most, I suppose) people find it bad practice not to include them (can also lead to errors/unwanted behaviors in some specific cases).

Comment: Why is `two` calling `two`? That would lead to an infinite loop because a function is continuously calling itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `two` was calling itself - you need to call `one` in `two`. You also have to call `two`:

```js
let x = 0
function one() {
    console.log(x);
}
function two() {
    one();
}
two();
```

Comment: It does though.

Comment: @Brent: It obviously works here as you can verify yourself. If it doesn't work for you then your code / environment is different. But we can't help you if we don't know about it.

Comment: oh wait I just realized I am defining the functions in two different scripts so one is being called before it initializes x.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't see it

Comment: @BrentTrenholme It should work as long as `x` (`let x = 0` here) is defined before calling `two();`.